# MOSFETS partly conducting

Tags: mosfet

This has happened to me probably ten times with N-channel MOSFETs. I have a 10Kohm resistor from the gate pin to GND, I have source connected to GND and drain connected to cathode of LED. Anode of LED is connected to +3V3. I apply 5V to gate pin, the LED lights, I take the 5V off and it stays on, not for a few seconds but permanently. I check drain and source for a short, I see that they are connected with a resistance of about 400 ohms while gate shows about 1 millivolt with a MOSFET that has a gate threshold of 2V at minimum. (meaning the MOSFET is fried?). MOSFET has max drain-source voltage of 60V and it can carry 20A. Tried with different MOSFETS using a 9V battery and a lab bench power supply.

What's wrong here? Please help me, I am desperate. I just "fried" four SMD MOSFETs on my custom board. How can it break with such small voltages and currents?

MOSFET: IPD025N06N

[image: schematic]

Comment: "What's wrong here?" Some people may care, others not, but your schematic is "upside down". Traditionally, ground is toward the bottom of the schematic, and Vcc or whatever the supply voltage is called, is at the top.

Comment: @All - Please stop answering this question in comments. That is not an allowed use of them (see [here](/help/privileges/comment) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)). Answer-comments cannot be edited to improve them, cannot be downvoted if they are wrong (i.e. they bypass proper site quality control) & cause other problems e.g. they can dissuade people from reading & voting on the *real* answers, if an answer is written in comments. They also don't count as answers in statistics, making our site look less useful i.e. they *harm our site*. Write proper answers instead. Thanks.

Comment: (The answer-comments have been deleted.)

Answer (score 2):

Try connect it this way instead (sorry for turning it upside down)

[image]

A little bit of explanation, the way the MOSFET is oriented in your schematics is that it will always conduct through the body diode. Why the FET is destroyed I don't know.

Comment: This what they describe in their question as being the wiring scheme already.

Comment: @tobalt It's not what they describe in their circuit though.

Comment: This schematic is better but there should be a resistor between the gate and the switch. Preferably a 10K resistor. Please correct the schematic.

Comment: Maybe "sorry for turning it upside down" should be "I turned it the conventional way up for you so that others can read it more easily"?

Comment: _"Why the FET is destroyed I don't know."_ In the original circuit \$3.3V - V_{LED}\$ is short-circuited over the MOSFET (there is no current limiting resistor)

Comment: @Velvet Maybe I'm being stupid here since I don't understand, how does that kill a MOSFET rated for 60 V, 90 A?

Comment: The issue is that there is nothing limiting the current.
(I'm not even sure if \$R_{DS(on)}\$ applies if operating in the reverse direction, but let's assume it does.)
So let's also assume \$V_{LED} = 2V\$ and \$R_{DS(on)} = 2.5mΩ\$.
\$I_{D} = (3.3V - V_{LED} - V_{SD})/R_{DS(on)} = (3.3V - 2V - 1V)/2.5mΩ = 120A\$.
A current limiting resistor (as seen in your circuit) would prevent the current from rising to damaging levels.

Comment: In addition, the 90 A only applies if the heat is adequately dissipated.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have drawn the NMOS in your schematic is wrong i.e., like pointed out by MiNiMe, you have interchanged the source and drain.

Do you really have no current limiting resistor in series with your LED? If yes, that is also an issue.